# Add script in comment on Pug

Tags: html, express, pug

How to add script in comment on Pug ?
I have two script to include on my web page :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Why not just conditionally add the scripts in node rather than conditional statements in the template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE conditional statements in Jade template engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853844/ie-conditional-statements-in-jade-template-engine)

Answer (score 1):

See [this page](https://pugjs.org/language/comments.html#conditional-comments) in the pug docs

> Pug does not have any special syntax for conditional comments. But since all lines beginning with < are treated as plain text, normal HTML style conditional comments will do fine.

So you can just use standard html for your conditional comments